# Delete Objects in S3 older than 90 days. (S3 Management Console )

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-policies

I want my s3 bucket to delete Objects older than 3 months. I am trying this in the s3 management console but I am getting confused about the option to select. I tried all these options but non of them deleted the objects.

```
 1. Expire current versions of objects.
 2. Permanently delete noncurrent versions of objects.
 3. Delete expired objects delete markers or incomplete multipart 
    uploads.
```

I have read many Articles but non of them helps.
Thanks

Comment: You want the first option, unless you have Versioning enabled on the bucket. However, it can take 24-48 hours for the process to start. Therefore, configure it and wait a day or so to check whether it is working.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup S3 Object LifeCycle Rule from AWS Console. You can read more detail from here: [Setting lifecycle configuration on a bucket - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-set-lifecycle-configuration-intro.html)